# JFrame with different panels inside

Tags: java, swing, menu, jframe, jpanel

I'm tasked to program a game.
A quite simple one, I'm thinking a `JFrame` with 3 different panels, `MenuPanel`, `GamePanel` and `HighScorePanel`.

Of course, when you start the game you see the `MenuPanel`, click "start" and `GamePanel` comes on.

I'm thinking that the `MenuPanel` should handle the buttons and so on.
And the frame should switch between the different panels that should be active.

Now, my questions are;

1. If the `MenuPanel` handles the buttons, how can it communicate with the frame so that the active panel will be switched if e.g. a "Play" button is pressed?
2. Does this design have apparent flaws?

Comment: The fact that you talk about panels 'communicating' suggests you are extending them.  Don't do that, simply create a panel instance and use it.  It is typically unnecessary to even hold a reference to a panel.

Comment: Well yes, I have Gamepanel extends JPanel.
Im not sure how Im supposed to accomplish it otherwise. All stuff to be drawn I was thinking to have in the GamePanels overwritten paintComponent(Graphics g) - method.

Comment: It is OK to extend panels for custom painting (though I typically prefer using a `BufferedImage` as a painting surface), but then, how do controls come into it?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).